# How can I execute this query through Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a raw query which looks like this:

```
SELECT sum(count) AS f FROM transactions WHERE userid = :userid AND
((date = :date_1 AND month = :month_1 and YEAR = :year_1) OR
 (date = :date_2 AND month = :month_2 and YEAR = :year_2) OR
 ...
 ...
 ...
 (date = :date_n AND month = :month_n and YEAR = :year_n);
```

The date-related parameters depend on an array consisting of dates, which looks like the following (the length of the array can vary):

```
[
  ['d' => 10, 'm' => 12, 'y' => 1994],
  ['d' => 30, 'm' => 1, 'y' => 2003]
  // ...
]
```

I'm unable to come up with the equivalent Eloquent statements. If I try:

```
$tr_query = Transactions::select(DB::raw('sum(count) as f'));

foreach ($dates as $date) {
  $tr_query->orWhere([
    'date' => $date['d'],
    'month' => $date['m'],
    'year' => $year['y']
  ]);
}

$tr_query->where('userid', $userid);
```

Internally, this results in:

```
SELECT sum(count) AS f FROM transactions WHERE
(date = ... and month = ... and year = ...) OR
(date = ... and month = ... and year = ...) OR
...
(date = ... and month = ... and year = ...) AND
userid = ...;
```

This is not the correct query, so how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is the nesting then you can do the following:

```
$tr_query = Transactions::select(DB::raw('sum(count) as f'));


$tr_query->where('userid', $userid);
$tr_query->where(function ($query) use ($dates) {
   foreach ($dates as $date) {
     $query->orWhere([
       'date' => $date['d'],
       'month' => $date['m'],
       'year' => $year['y']
     ]);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [the `where()` closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#parameter-grouping):

```
$tr_query = Transactions::select(DB::raw('sum(count) as f'))
    ->where('userid', $userid);
    ->where(function($q) use($dates) {
        foreach ($dates as $date) {
            $q->orWhere([
                'date' => $date['d'],
                'month' => $date['m'],
                'year' => $year['y']
            ]);
        }
    })->get();
```